# Writing an Aggregator that takes any orderable spark datatype

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning about custom Spark Aggregators and I'm trying to implement a "MinN" function which returns an array of the N smallest items in the column. I'd like it to work for integers, decimals, and timestamps.

This works for doubles only:

```
case class MinN(col: String, cutoff: Int = 5)
  extends Aggregator[Row, ArrayBuffer[Double], ArrayBuffer[Double]] with Serializable {

  def zero =  ArrayBuffer[Double]()
  def reduce(acc: ArrayBuffer[Double], x: Row) = {
    val curval = x.getAs[Double](col)
    if (acc.length < cutoff){
      acc.append(curval)
    } else {
      val maxOfMins = acc.max
      if (curval < maxOfMins) {
        acc(acc.indexOf(maxOfMins)) = curval
      }
    }
    acc
  }

  def merge(acc1: ArrayBuffer[Double], acc2: ArrayBuffer[Double]) = ({
    (acc1 ++ acc2).sorted.take(cutoff)
  })

  def finish(acc: ArrayBuffer[Double]) = acc

  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[ArrayBuffer[Double]] = ExpressionEncoder()
  override def outputEncoder: Encoder[Option[Double]] = ExpressionEncoder()
}
```

I then try to make the aggregator generic by changing the declaration to `MinN[T : Ordering]`, the comparison to `implicitly[Ordering[T]].lt(curval, maxOfMins)`, and all the `[Double]`s to `[T]`s. That gives the following compiler error:

```
Error:(58, 74) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[Nothing]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]]
Note: Nothing <: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[T], but trait Encoder is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[ArrayBuffer[T]] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. I don't even really want to make the `MinN` function parameterized like that (so a caller would have to write `MinN[Double]`. I'd like to create something like the builtin `min` function, which retains the (spark) datatype of its input.

*edit*

I'm using the MinN aggregator like this:

```
  val minVolume = new MinN[Double]("volume").toColumn
  val p = dataframe.agg(minVolume.name("minVolume"))
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you create the instance of the MinN[T] version?

Comment: @Alfilercio I put in an example. Your answer throws the same compilation error as before.

Answer (score 2):

I believe spark can't handle this high level abstraction. You can transform the aggregation to something like this

```
case class MinN[T : Ordering](cutoff: Int = 5)(
  implicit arrEnc: Encoder[mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]])
  extends Aggregator[T, mutable.ArrayBuffer[T], mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]] with Serializable {

  def zero =  mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]()
  def reduce(acc: mutable.ArrayBuffer[T], x: T) = {
    mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty
  }

  def merge(acc1: mutable.ArrayBuffer[T], acc2: mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]) = ({
    mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty
  })

  def finish(acc: mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]) = acc

  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]] = implicitly
  override def outputEncoder: Encoder[mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]] = implicitly
}
```

and will compile, you were missing the encoders, so they are extracted in the constructor. But using it in an example like:

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("jander").master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

```
import spark.implicits._

val custom = MinN[Double](2).toColumn

val d: Double = 1.1

val df = List(
  ("A", 1.1),
  ("A", 1.2),
  ("A", 1.3),
  ).toDF("col1", "col2")

df.groupBy("col1").agg(custom("col2") as "a").show()
```

Will throw an exception in runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'Aggregate [col1#10], [col1#10, minn(MinN(2), None, None, None, newInstance(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData) AS value#1, mapobjects(MapObjects_loopValue0, false, DoubleType, assertnotnull(lambdavariable(MapObjects_loopValue0, false, DoubleType, false)), input[0, array<double>, false], Some(class scala.collection.immutable.List)), newInstance(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData) AS value#0, StructField(value,ArrayType(DoubleType,false),false), true, 0, 0)[col2] AS a#16];;
```